# Avoid pattern matching inside a monad in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I have the following definitions:

```
env = DataMap.fromList [
                ("foo",42), ("bar",69),
                ("baz",27), ("qux",0)
               ]


doSomething:: String →  Writer [String] Int
doSomething s = do
            let v = DataMap.lookup s env
            case v of
                Nothing →  fail $  s ++ " not found"
                Just a →  do
                            tell [s ++ " →  " ++ (show a)]
                            return a
```

What really is annoying me about this code is the use of the pattern matching inside the doSomething. It completely defeats the purpose of using monads. Is there any way of re-writing the doSomething function using only monadic functions without using monad transformers?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the [`maybe`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Maybe.html#v:maybe) function?

Comment: But... isn't this exactly what monad transformers are for? Why not use one? Especially since you're using `fail` right now, which is not really considered a good practice...

Comment: The maybe function is implemented using pattern matching (http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.2/html/libraries/base/src/Data-Maybe.html) so it's still in there, though you don't have to look at it.

Comment: @larsmans , your suggestion was correct, thanks!

Comment: @C.A.McCann , I see that fail is not got practice, I'll avoid it in the future.

Comment: @rickythesk8r , Good thing Haskell has hidden the pattern matching! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @larsmans said, the easiest way is to use `maybe` function:

```
doSomething:: String ->  Writer [String] Int
doSomething s = maybe n (\a -> t a >> return a) $ DataMap.lookup s env where
    n = fail $ s ++ " not found"
    t a = tell [s ++ " ->  " ++ show a]
```

Monad transformers are of little help here. You will need one to *combine* several calculations which both fail and write. In case of just one calculation you don't need monads.

Also, I'd use `ErrorT` transformer and `throwError` function to report error instead of `fail`. See http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Error_reporting_strategies for possible ways to handle errors.

Comment: It never occurred to me that fail was despised! I read up on it, makes sense now. Everything works great, thanks! I'll see what ErrorT has to offer.

Comment: I prefer `EitherT` and http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors, but second the suggestion to use such an error handling strategy :)

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of clunky, but it's how I'd do it.

```
doSomething2 :: String -> Writer [String] Int
doSomething2 s =
    maybe (fail $ s ++ " not found") id $ do
       a <- DataMap.lookup s env
       return $ (tell [s ++ " -> " ++ show a] >> return a)
```